# Writing and saving methods in R package

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I'm updating my `R` package, named `psda`. For this, I created a method `summary` of the class `plr`, both created by me as shows the MWE. I have two questions:

(1) How can I save the method file? (I tried to use `summary.plr.R`.)

(2) Is correct this way in third line?

The error message showed by check is:

> summary.plr.Rd: non-ASCII input and no declared encoding
>      problem found in 'summary.plr.Rd'

## MWE

```
#' Summarizing Polygonal Linear Regression
#' @description \code{summary} method for class "\code{plr}".
#' @method summary plr
#' @export 
summary.plr <- function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) {
    some_code...
    class(ans) <- "summary.plr"
    ans
}
```

## Edit

The Polygonal linear regression (plr) is a function with same outputs of the `lm` function. For example, we can change the term `some_code...`and to use

```
## Start ##
x <- runif(100, -3, 3)
y <- 2 * x + rnorm(100)
res <- lm(y~x)
## End ##

#' Polygonal linear regression
#' @description  plr is used to fit polygonal linear models.
#' @export

plr <- function(formula, data, model = TRUE, ...){
  some_core... 
  class(res) <- 'plr'
  res
}
```

Comment: What are you doing before this function? That is, show code that creates some object `x` (likely of class `"plr"`); if you do something other than `summary(x)` on this object, then include that code as well.

Comment: The error seems to be in the documentation `.Rd` file, not your R code. What does that file look like? Did you have any warnings or errors when you roxygenized your package?

Comment: Yes, the error message is < Non-standard file/directory found at top level: 'psda'>